# Hidden JQGrid takes up space

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a JQGrid inside an accordion. When the grid has no posts it is hidden, but still takes up space. I understand, it might be caused by some child elements that has style attribute 'position' set to 'absolute'.

How do I find out if that is the case, and how do I change it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's possible the grid itself is set to `position:relative;`  (to contain the absolute child elements) if the grid then has some padding or borders it will not completely disappear even if empty

to check look at the site in FF and use Firebug, to inspect the element, it will tell you what styles are still being applied

I suppose you could then choose to "`display: none;`" if there's no content

Comment: Thank you! **display: none;** did the trick. CSS is not my cup of tea ;)